# Avoiding memory errors using set comprehension

Tags: python, memory-management, set, list-comprehension

I'm constructing a large set by reading through a big data set (~250k rows), and for the sake of efficiency I decided to construct the set using set comprehension, but I keep running into memory errors, which makes sense, as I believe the garbage collector doesn't work during the evaluation of a set comprehension. Actual source code is below:

```
def parsedData(filePath):
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as rawData:
        reader = csv.reader(rawData, delimiter=",")
        allJobs = {Job(rawJob(row)) for row in reader}
    return allJobs
```

Is there any way to force the garbage collector to clear when it's about to reach a memory error? Is there a faster way to do this? Would I run into the same memory issues using a lambda function instead of a set comprehension?

Comment: How does your `Job` class define equality?  Is it possible you just don't have enough memory to handle even just the unique items from the file?

Comment: There shouldn't be any duplicates in the original file, the set casting was purely to make iteration faster the size of the data file is around 440 MB though.

Comment: While I don't think it has any bearing on the memory issues you're having, I wouldn't describe `set(func(stuff) for stuff in generator)` as a set comprehension. A comprehension uses the set-literal syntax: `{func(stuff) for stuf in generator}`.

Comment: Corrected, is there a real difference between the two?

Comment: I don't think there's any significant difference, but I'm not certain of that. But to get to your actual issue, I'm not sure that you can iterate any faster over a set than over a list or tuple, and the set is likely to have more memory overhead. Python's sets are implemented as hash tables which need to keep empty a significant fraction of their table slots in order to work efficiently. Have you tried a list comprehension instead of the set comprehension?

Comment: How big are the `Job` instances? A `set` of 250k numbers occupies about 8.4MB(plus the memory taken by the integer objects themselves, which should be around 8MB, so for small objects it shouldn't give you a `MemoryError`.

Comment: The size of the csv the jobs are all made from is about 440 MB

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: That doesn't really answer the question.  It depends how complex the `Job` class is and how much data it stores, and of what types.

Comment: Is there any way to re-use the `rawobj` instance inside loop so a temporary one doesn't have to be created each iteration?

Comment: @BrenBarn Right now the Job class is basically just a series of strings that correspond to the fields of the csv, so it should be very close to that.

Comment: @martineau Not totally sure what you're suggesting, could you expand that thought out a bit in an answer?

Comment: What do you need to do with the data? Have you checked out the [garbage collector](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html) and [resource](http://docs.python.org/2/library/resource.html) modules?

Comment: @grc data is part of a kaggle competition and I would like to be able to do sophisticated data manipulation on this, but it's starting to seem like I'll have to do everything on the fly, which isn't the worst thing.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: I was assuming the `rawJob(row)` call within the `Job(rawJob(row))` in the set comp. creates a temporary object (and consumes memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a reason this may be happening:

To create a unique set of custom objects your object must, at a minimum, implement `__eq__` and `__hash__`.

Demo:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.val

li=['i am uniq','i am uniq','i am uniq','not really','not really','not really']        
print set(Obj(e) for e in li)
```

Prints

```
set([i am uniq, i am uniq, not really, not really, i am uniq, not really])
```

Now add the required `__eq__` and `__hash__` methods:

```
class Obj(object):
    def __init__(self,val):
        self.val=val
        self.hash=hash(val)

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.val

    def __eq__(self,other):
        return self.hash==other.hash    

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hash        

li=['i am uniq','i am uniq','i am uniq','really','really','really']        
print set(Obj(e) for e in li)
```

Prints:

```
set([i am uniq, really])
```

Without a proper hash and eq, you can see you won't have a set at all; you will have an unordered list based on the `Jobs` obj id. To Python, in other words, even objects that you define as 'the same' will be treated as different objects because each has a different obj id. This 'set' will actually be quite a bit larger than the equivalent list would be.

---

That aside -- A more memory efficient way to do this is probably to use a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html) in numpy with a generator to read the file row by row.

Strategy:

1. Open the file
2. Determine the total line count of the file -- that is the worst case total records in the file
3. Rewind the file
4. Read the first record and determine the most efficient record structure for a numpy array based on records of the line data (ints, floats, bytes, etc) This is much denser than the equivalent would be in Python objects
5. Rewind the file
6. If you want to have a hash to uniqify your data, add that to the record
7. Pre allocate the numpy array to `lines X records` size
8. Create a generator to read the file line by line and place each record in the numpy array
9. Don't add the duplicative records (based on the hash)
10. Resize the numpy array for the total duplicative records not added...

Comment: So, numpy array didn't quite get me to working code, but I ended up just doing everything as I went through the file since I feel it was probably bad form to read that much data in inside a comprehension anyway. I think the numpy array is a valuable tool for other a number of other similar solutions though and it will avoid the memory error in a number of places.

Comment: Great! Numpy does have a learning curve... Did it turn out you needed to add `__hash__` and `__eq__` to Jobs?

Comment: Nah, the training set actually did not have duplicates, but it was a useful suggestion and I think it will help people out that have similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

You say:

> There shouldn't be any duplicates in the original file, the set
>   casting was purely to make iteration faster

Murphy's Law says there will be duplicates. "make iteration faster" seems to me like premature AND dubious optimisation.

Some triage suggestions:

(0) Test it on a small number of rows to ensure that it is working properly (especially ensuring that Job objects are hashable AND that the hash method genuinely mirrors your definition of uniqueness) before you start worrying about memory and CPU efficiency.

(1) Keep it simple i.e. avoid set comprehensions, generators, etc ... do it the good ol' fashioned one at a time method. Comprehensions etc are elegant but are restricted to use cases where nothing can go wrong ... you are processing half-a-gig text files.

(2) Insert some debug code so that you can see how far it is getting before it runs out of memory.

(3) Check for duplicates!

```
def parsedData(filePath):
    allJobs = set()
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as rawData:
        reader = csv.reader(rawData, delimiter=",")
        for rownum, row in enumerate(reader, start=1):
            job = Job(rawJob(row))
            if job in allJobs:
                pass # add code to display dupe
            else:
                allJobs.add(job)
            if rownum % 10000 == 0:
                print rownum, "rows; ", len(allJobs), "unique"
    return allJobs
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

As @Hyperboreus pointed out, this will throw `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file`. I'm leaving it here just in case it is useful. I think the best solution to this problem will probably involve leaving the file open and using generators to only read the data at the last minute.

---

Try this:

```
def parsedData(filePath):
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as rawData:
        reader = csv.reader(rawData, delimiter=",")
        allJobs = (Job(rawJob(row)) for row in reader)
    return allJobs
```

It uses a generator expression instead of a set comprehension to create and return a generator.

From the [python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators):

> The performance improvement from the use of generators is the result
>   of the lazy (on demand) generation of values, which translates to
>   lower memory usage. Furthermore, we do not need to wait until all the
>   elements have been generated before we start to use them.

Comment: This may be an idea, but if the OP needs a sequence instead of a iterable then it wont solve his problem.

Comment: I don't think this works, as allJobs is a generator over a closed file object. It might throw "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file"

Answer (score 0):

If all rows are unique and you get MemoryError even if you use a list comprehension instead of the set then you can make the function to be a generator to avoid loading all jobs at once:

```
def get_jobs(filePath):
    with open(filePath, 'rb') as rawData:
        reader = csv.reader(rawData, delimiter=",")
        for row in reader:
            yield Job(rawJob(row))
```

You could use it as:

```
for job in get_jobs(path):
    process(job)
```